# Data binding from slots?

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit-element, lit, lit-html

I've been working with [Lit](https://lit.dev/) and recently I got into a weird issue where I couldn't get the property change detection in [`updated`](https://lit.dev/docs/components/lifecycle/#updated) lifecycle callback when the property value (in this case: `myProperty`) is changed for the component which is loaded via slot.

This is what I've been doing as an example:

**parentComponent.ts**

```
@property({ type: Object })
public myProperty: MediaStream;

constructor() {
  super();
  this.myProperty = new MediaStream();
}

triggerUpdate() {
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: true,
     })
    .then(async (stream) => {
      this.myProperty = stream;
    });
}

render() {
  return html`
    <child-component>
      <div slot="grand-child-slot">
        <grand-child-component
          .myProperty="${this.myProperty}"
        >
        </grand-child-component>
      </div>
    </child-component>
  `
}
```

**grandChildComponent.ts**

```
@property({ type: Object })
public myProperty: MediaStream;

updated(changedProperties) {
   super.updated(changedProperties);
   if (changedProperties.has('myProperty')) {
     console.log(`Property "myProperty" has been updated to: ${this.myProperty}`);
   }
 }
```

In the above example, the `console.log` never execute when the `myProperty` is updated to a new value.

If I reload the `grand-child-component` within the slot then it works. I would expect the change to happen real time without any reloading the template.

Does anybody has a clue why this happens when used within a slot?

Comment: One thing that is unclear from this example is if `myProperty` within `grand-child-component` is a reactive property? If `myProperty` has `@property()`, then this should work.

In `grandChildComponent.ts` how is `myProperty` defined?

Comment: @YourCodeThings Thanks for your response! Probably needed coffee yesterday ;) (made some mistakes so updated the question and this comment with all the details)`myProperty` is a Lit reactive property within `grand-child-component`. `myProperty` is of type `MediaStream` not boolean. My bad! The question is now updated with all the details.

Comment: Because you are now passing an object, it's far more likely that this property is not changing reference, and is a mutated version of the original. In this case the child will not update.

See [mutating object](https://lit.dev/docs/components/properties/#mutating-properties) documentation. In this case, your parent may need to call `requestUpdate` on the `grand-child-component`. This happens because even though the parent re-renders, the `this.myProperty` is a mutated version of the same object. When the child Lit element checks, "did my properties change", they haven't, so don't re-render.

Comment: Thanks! You might be right. Let me check that part of my code to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare class property in lit it will not trigger an update. However you can explicitly trigger update by calling [requestUpdate](https://lit.dev/docs/components/lifecycle/#requestUpdate)

```
triggerUpdate() {
  this.someProp = true;
  this.requestUpdate()
}
```

**or**

Alternatively you can declare [state](https://lit.dev/docs/api/decorators/#state) reactive property that will trigger an update when it changes

```
@state() someProp = false;


triggerUpdate() {
  this.someProp = true;
}

render() {
  return html`
    <child-component>
      <div slot="grand-child-slot">
        <grand-child-component
          .hasUpdated="${this.hasUpdated}"
        >
        </grand-child-component>
      </div>
    </child-component>
  `
}
```

Update your `hasUpdated` props name to another name hence hasUpdated is reserved word in lit

Comment: Thanks for your answer! `hasUpdated` is a reactive property. I've used property decorator (updated my question). So I would expect to trigger the re-render in this case. But I will see how `@state` would work.

I've tried `this.requestUpdate()` but it never worked.

Comment: @HiteshMisro hasUpdated is reserved property please rename it to something else:https://lit.dev/docs/components/lifecycle/#hasupdated

Comment: It's not the property name I've been using in my project. I've just created this example to replicate the situation. I'll update my question.

Comment: `hasUpdated` is now `myProperty` ;)

Comment: @HiteshMisro please update with repo